# How do I see request cookies in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cookies

In Firefox and Safari, you can see the cookies being passed in the request in the network tab. For example, if you visit walmart.com and inspect the `GET facebook.com/tr/xxxx` requests, you can see that facebook is passing the `_fbp` cookie among others in the "Request cookies" section of this tab:

[image]

Chrome occasionally has this tab for certain requests, but not for all requests like Firefox does. Does anyone know if there's a way to show request cookies for all requests in Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

In the developer tab related to the cookie, you can view only the cookie related to the response. In order to understand which headers was sent during the request, you have to move under the `network` tab and then you can click over your request. Here you can now see the headers related to your request.

Answer (score 1):

In the Chrome DevTools window or pane (brought up with Ctrl+Shift+J or "Inspect" under the right-click context menu) there is now an "Application" tab that, with the correct items selected under the "Storage" section in the left-hand panel will show the cookie information. These are the cookies that are sent back in requests. (Cookies that have been blocked will not appear here.)

[image: Application tab / Storage / Cookies]